Name my daughter Syedzadi
Assalamualikum,
Can I name my daughter "Syedzadi"?
It means "Daughter of Syed"
Please answer.

in general yes, why not? but if Syed stands for "سید" and in your culture commonly people have the name who are really "سید", then that would be problematic I guess, that will be like pretending to be something that you are not.

Yes, her dad is a real Syed.

According to Ahadeeth, among the rights children have on their parent is their right to have good names. If the child's father is Syed, so would be the child, so maybe there is no need to call the child as "a child of a Syed" and I've seen a lot of Syed people's name bearing a Syed (or Syedah) as prefix, like in SyedAli, or SyedahZahra, or else, or a Sadat at the end like in ZahraSadat. Anyway, that is your choice and SyedZadeh on its own has no Islamic problem, and rather is a matter of culture. For example it is a good practice that the name is such that people will know from the child's name if the child is a boy or a girl. Also, if you are from a culture but have immigrated to live in another culture, it is a good practice that you choose a name which will not make problem for the child in school and beyond. Just my 5 cents ...
